# How to store large individual set (ABox) out of ontology preserving reasoning results?

Tags: owl, ontology

I have a quite simple ontology written in OWL 2, describing my particular world (TBox).

Since I have to store a lot of individuals, I would like to avoid scalability problems of triplestores, storing them out of the ontology (e.g., in a database table). At the same time, I would like to exploit reasoning capabilities.

For example, if I stored my individuals assertions directly into my ontology:

```
:Mary a :Female
:Mary :motherOf :John
...
```

with an opportune modelling, I could entail after a reasoning that:

```
:Mary a :Parent
:Mary a :Mother
...
```

...but what if I stored my individuals assertions outside of my ontology? Is there a framework/best practice to manage this scenario?

Comment: What do you use to store the ontology and instances right now? There are triple stores that are tuned for storage and performance reasons, taking into consideration different reasoning capabilities possible. 

There is a wide range of possible applications to use. I usually use [GraphDB free]  https://ontotext.com/products/graphdb/ for my purposes, it works well when provided the suitable resources, and you can specify the type reasoning you want to perform as well.

Comment: During my tests I'm just using Protégé, therefore I do not have a current solution in mind. But as far as I know, storing all individual triples in OWL files and managing them with, for example, OWL API, could lead to performance problems. Is GraphDB free kind of like neo4j?

Comment: Yes it's free and you don't need to care about performance, it's never your problem.

Comment: But you can as well do some research on available triple stores and find out what is the best that fits your requirements.

Comment: Why isn't performance a problem?

Comment: It is not your problem, because the database engine takes care of it! This is why basically such engines exist. Performance could, however, of course, be tuned and manipulated depending on multiple criteria. The main scenario, however, is that you ask queries, and the engine answers them! You don't really care how it answers. Look at http://factforge.net/sparql for a live demo on GraphDB.

Comment: When you say 'database engine' do you mean the engine of the triplestore? Sorry for the trivial question, but I come from the classical db world and I'm quite new to the semantic one.

Comment: Yes, I mean the triple store, which is a database, as well ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147832/discussion-between-superciccio14-and-median-hilal).